# Adobe Edge animation glitch

Tags: javascript, adobe-edge

Is there a way to make going from hover state to hover state when each one triggers the same animation respond without a glitch?

See my [site](http://hithouse.businesscatalyst.com/index.html) and hover over "news" in the navigation and it will animate but if you hover over "about us" while its animating then it glitches.

Ultimately I want it to function like [this page](http://thehithouse.com/) has.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I guess you have your site under maintenance.
Try converting them into symbols that might help...

I can help you with the site if you send me the animate file.

Regards,
Krunal Puri